# Because of which element the world has come together?

Tags: sankhara

The world seems to have come together. We have United Nations which is a symbol of the unity of the nations.However things come together because of an element.  That element can be greed or aversion or delusion or education or faith or love or anger... etc...
Therefore I would like to ask : Because of which element the world has come together?

Answer (score 1):

Craving. Refer to [SN 12.44](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.44/en/bodhi)....

Answer (score 0):

Similar food, tendency, is why being gather together again and again, good householder. The virtuous, the smoker, the hunters, the Balas...

The lower the preferences, the larger the gatherings, naturally and vici versa.

People, place of dwelling, food, whether... those are matters of Upanissayapaccaya (strong condition causes), developed over long, long time and hard to leave that wheel...

That is why the is so much message in the [Mangala Sutta](https://sangham.net/en/tipitaka/sut/kn/snp/snp.2.04.than).

And what are the highest uniforms? Stream-enter dwelling with Stream-enter... Arahats with Arahats.

Where ever one tends to, there he arrives.

Worlds come and presist by craving and not-knowing, since unimaginable beginning, time. For more on how world arises detail investigation of the secound Noble Truth will explain and the third, how this Dukkha dissolves.

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, excange, other world-binding trades but for possibility to increase Upanissaya toward liberation from this wheel]*

Answer (score 0):

> Because of which element the world has come together?

It'd require the mind capacity of a Sammasambuddha to be able to see all the necessary and sufficient elements and conditions for the formation of the world, kinda like it'd take scientists much time and effort to piece together all the elements needed for a seed to develop into a tree, which are many: root seed, water, soil conditions, sunlight, appropriate temperature, fertilizer and nutrients, etc...

Answer (score -1):

The element you are searching for is Mahakaruna (*Great Responsiveness*):

> The final attribute of emptiness to be mentioned is a quality peculiar to the Buddhist analysis: responsiveness. It is the third and final denominator in the list of categories or aspects by which emptiness can be defined: essence, nature, responsiveness. It appears anomalous, an attribute rather than a category. The third logical category is function, or manifest function, and the attribute found in its stead is responsiveness and its qualifier is all-pervasive. Viewed as a functional attribute of inner space, total presence, and light, the implication is that the dynamic, the intentionality, the purpose of being is compassion, which is a synonym of responsiveness and demonstrable as the responsive aspect of love. It is this compassion that is coextensive with space, the buddha-heart pervading all beings. Viewed as the potential form or manifestation of emptiness, the implication appears to be that every vibration of body, speech, and mind is a form of compassionate energy, nothing excluded. Consider the distinction between responsiveness and compassion. In Dzogchen, compassion is much more than the virtue of loving-kindness. Nor does the word compassion in the Dzogchen context denote its English etymological meaning, “suffering together” or “empathy,” although both these meanings may be inferred. Essentially, compassion indicates an open and receptive mind responding spontaneously to the exigencies of an ever-changing field of vibration to sustain the optimal awareness that serves self-and-others’ ultimate desire for liberation and well-being. The conventional meaning of compassion denotes the latter, active part of this definition, and, due to the accretions of Christian connotation in the West, response is limited to specifically virtuous activity. Responsiveness defines the origin and cause of selfless activity that can encompass all manner of response. On this nondual Dzogchen path, virtue is the effect, not the cause; the ultimate compassionate response is whatever action optimizes presence — loving-kindness is the automatic function of primal awareness.

Excerpt From: “The Flight of the Garuda,” by Keith Dowman, Wisdom Publications, 2003, pgs 37-38

Mahakaruna is realized through Great Responsiveness Meditation—the practice of Avalokitasvara. See: “Jamyang Khyentse Chökyi Lodrö’s Prophecy of Things to Come” https://medium.com/p/c9e6e2c54f23